# opacity only on watermark not on background

Tags: css

I want to lighten the watermark of text but not on background.when i use opacity entire input is getting lightened.

here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ns8xe/

HTML

```
<select id="selMemberType" size="0" class="empty selectPlaceholder" tabindex="3">
            <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">Career Level</option>
            <option value="1">Student (High School)</option>
            <option value="2">Student</option>
            <option value="3">Entry Level</option>
            <option value="4">Experienced</option>
            <option value="5">Manager</option>
            <option value="6">Executive</option>
            <option value="7">Senior Executive</option>
            <option value="8">Celebrity</option>
        </select>
```

css

```
#selMemberType {
height: 32px!important;
border-top: 1px solid #666;
border-right: 1px solid #666;
border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
border-left: 1px solid #666;
border-radius: 4px;
background-color: rgba(30,31,32,.58);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #555;
box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #000;
font: normal 18px futuraltbook!important;
clear: both;
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
padding: 0;
width: 546px;

}
```

any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 3):

Use [`rgba()`](http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/) to set the alpha opacity value. It will only change the opacity of the font color (also works great on background colors). Please note that it isn't supported in all browsers, so you'll need to set a fallback for those who doesn't support it.

```
color: rgb( 0,0,0); /* fallback for not-rgba-supporting-browsers */
color: rgba( 0,0,0, 0.5);
```

Check your [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ns8xe/1/).

Comment: i want the watermark color match with other input boxes,some how it is not matching what should i be doing to get very light grey color watermark..i tried blur but its  not coming...can u pls help me with this